# Display Select Name According to Database Value in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning PHP yet. I am successfully able to display text fields value like below in my form.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text"
           name="unit"
           id="unit"
           value="<?php if(isset($_GET['project_id'])){echo $row['unit'];}?>"
           class="form-control"
           required>
</div>
```

I want use similar things for my select form. I have one value called status in my database table. `if status = 1 then I want display Open, if status = 2 then I want display Closed`. I am not able to think properly condition for select form.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select name="status" id="status" class="select2">
        <option value="">--Project Status--</option>                            
    </select>
```

Let me know if someone can please help me for achieve my goal. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: `if ($status == 2){ ?><option value="closed"> Closed</option> <?php }elseif($status == 1){ ?><option value="open"> Open</option><?php }else{ ?><option value="unknown"> unknown</option><?php }` Something like this ?

Comment: @executable Yes, But How I can apply it in my code?

Comment: Are you trying to populate the option fields or select one based on the `$status`value?

Comment: What do you mean by apply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it like this :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select name="status" id="status" class="select2">
        <?php if (!isset($_GET['project_id'])) { ?>
        <option value="">--Project Status--</option>
        <?php } ?>
        <option value="1" <?php echo $row['status'] == '1' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Open</option>                            
        <option value="2" <?php echo $row['status'] == '2' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Closed</option>                            
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: its nice, but How I can I use my condition if(isset($_GET['project_id']) in Mind?

Comment: Added conditional `project_id` value

Comment: Thanks for it. I have still one issue, if(isset($_GET['project_id']) { I want show open and closed only } else I want show { Project Status, Open, Closed}, sorry but it will help me lot. Thanks

Comment: Sir, still have one issue, in else condition, I want show open and closed too so user can select as per requirements. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your statuses into an array like this:

```
$statuses = [
    1 => 'Open',
    2 => 'Closed',
];
```

Lets say you have a project and it has some status id, lets put it into `$projectStatus`

Html would look like:

```
<select name="status" id="status" class="select2">
<?php foreach ($statuses as $key => $status) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php echo $key == $projectStatus ? 'selected' : '' ?><?php echo $status ?></option>                            
<?php } ?>
</select>
```